# How to make a Graph API post (Facebook check-in) using Ionic or Angular

Tags: facebook, angular, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have successfully added Facebook login functionality to my Ionic 3 application following [the Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) and I can receive needed user profile data from Graph API.

Now I can't figure out how to add the check-in option.

[Facebook Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/user/feed/) say check-in is now only possible by POSTING the data with the user that has 'publish_actions' rights.

So something like this should work:

`this.facebook.api("me/feed?place=123123123123", ["publish_actions"])`

(*where place is the Place ID of the page I want to check-in*)

But it does not work because the `api` method only creates `GET` requests and there is no way to set the request method to `POST`

Also the cordova's [Facebook](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) plugin also doesn't seem like it supports posting to Graph API.

I can't find any examples of Ionic check-in code examples or any way of doing this.

Anyone have any experience with this?

I have all the data needed to make this Graph API request - User Id, required permissions and place Id.

Please ask if additional info is required.

Comment: Checkins have been deprecated a while ago, in favor of posts with location information attached. (Field `place`)

Comment: Yep, that's why I suspect that I have to use the `api` method